# [android Side By Side Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, google-cardboard

Hi i want to show a live camera preview side by side on my Android Phone.
Like this:

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Ngo4tD4AvWY/U8JOHxxQ9KI/AAAAAAAACK8/NZjnw1Yqg8A/w384-h287/2.jpg

It works if just the left half screen shows the live preview or just the right side,
but if i want to show the left and the rigth side simultaneously i just get a black screen
And i dont know why.

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.test.normaltest.sbscameraview" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private CameraView cameraView1;
    private CameraView cameraView2;
    private Camera mCamera1;
    private Camera mCamera2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCamera1 = getCameraInstance();
        cameraView1 = new CameraView(this, mCamera1);
        cameraView2 = new CameraView(this, mCamera1);

        FrameLayout preview1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview1);
        preview1.addView(cameraView1);

        FrameLayout preview2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview2);
        preview2.addView(cameraView2);
    }

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("camera", "null");
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }
}
```

CameraView

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;


    public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);

        mCamera = camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Log.i("CameraView", "surfaceChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can only open a camera once.

Comment: Yes and i just do it once. in the "getCameraInstance" method and then i give the object to two SurfaceView Objects.
It also works if i create the two cameraViews and just add the "cameraView2"

Comment: "i give the object to two SurfaceView Objects" -- a `Camera` can only work with one `SurfaceHolder` at a time.

Comment: ok, and is there any possibility to copy maybe the surface or the image comming from the camera and show it on the other half ?

Comment: You could use the camera preview frame API and use that to update two things at once, though I don't know what sort of frame rate you will get. There may be other options for doing this more directly, but I do not know what they are.

Comment: You can direct the camera preview to a SurfaceTexture, then render the texture with GLES twice.  See for example the "texture from camera" activity in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).

Answer (score 2):

You can use these codes to open camera on Google Cardboard.

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.oculab.mehmettaha.vrcamera" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

CardboardOverlayView.java

```
public class CardboardOverlayView extends LinearLayout {
private static final String TAG = CardboardOverlayView.class.getSimpleName();
private final CardboardOverlayEyeView mLeftView;
private final CardboardOverlayEyeView mRightView;
private AlphaAnimation mTextFadeAnimation;

public CardboardOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    mLeftView = new CardboardOverlayEyeView(context, attrs);
    mLeftView.setLayoutParams(params);
    addView(mLeftView);

    mRightView = new CardboardOverlayEyeView(context, attrs);
    mRightView.setLayoutParams(params);
    addView(mRightView);

    // Set some reasonable defaults.
    setDepthOffset(0.016f);
    setColor(Color.rgb(150, 255, 180));
    setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mTextFadeAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    mTextFadeAnimation.setDuration(5000);
}

public void show3DToast(String message) {
    setText(message);
    setTextAlpha(1f);
    mTextFadeAnimation.setAnimationListener(new EndAnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            setTextAlpha(0f);
        }
    });
    startAnimation(mTextFadeAnimation);
}

private abstract class EndAnimationListener implements Animation.AnimationListener {
    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
}

private void setDepthOffset(float offset) {
    mLeftView.setOffset(offset);
    mRightView.setOffset(-offset);
}

private void setText(String text) {
    mLeftView.setText(text);
    mRightView.setText(text);
}

private void setTextAlpha(float alpha) {
    mLeftView.setTextViewAlpha(alpha);
    mRightView.setTextViewAlpha(alpha);
}

private void setColor(int color) {
    mLeftView.setColor(color);
    mRightView.setColor(color);
}

/**
 * A simple view group containing some horizontally centered text underneath a horizontally
 * centered image.
 *
 * This is a helper class for CardboardOverlayView.
 */
private class CardboardOverlayEyeView extends ViewGroup {
    private final ImageView imageView;
    private final TextView textView;
    private float offset;

    public CardboardOverlayEyeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        imageView = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);  // Preserve aspect ratio.
        addView(imageView);

        textView = new TextView(context, attrs);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14.0f);
        textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setShadowLayer(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, Color.DKGRAY);
        addView(textView);
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        imageView.setColorFilter(color);
        textView.setTextColor(color);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    public void setTextViewAlpha(float alpha) {
        textView.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    public void setOffset(float offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        // Width and height of this ViewGroup.
        final int width = right - left;
        final int height = bottom - top;

        // The size of the image, given as a fraction of the dimension as a ViewGroup. We multiply
        // both width and heading with this number to compute the image's bounding box. Inside the
        // box, the image is the horizontally and vertically centered.
        final float imageSize = 0.12f;

        // The fraction of this ViewGroup's height by which we shift the image off the ViewGroup's
        // center. Positive values shift downwards, negative values shift upwards.
        final float verticalImageOffset = -0.07f;

        // Vertical position of the text, specified in fractions of this ViewGroup's height.
        final float verticalTextPos = 0.52f;

        // Layout ImageView
        float imageMargin = (1.0f - imageSize) / 2.0f;
        float leftMargin = (int) (width * (imageMargin + offset));
        float topMargin = (int) (height * (imageMargin + verticalImageOffset));
        imageView.layout(
                (int) leftMargin, (int) topMargin,
                (int) (leftMargin + width * imageSize), (int) (topMargin + height * imageSize));

        // Layout TextView
        leftMargin = offset * width;
        topMargin = height * verticalTextPos;
        textView.layout(
                (int) leftMargin, (int) topMargin,
                (int) (leftMargin + width), (int) (topMargin + height * (1.0f - verticalTextPos)));
    }
}
  }
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends CardboardActivity implements CardboardView.StereoRenderer, OnFrameAvailableListener {

private static final String TAG = "VRCamMtMMainAc";
private static final int GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = 0x8D65;
private Camera camera;

private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "attribute vec4 position;" +
                "attribute vec2 inputTextureCoordinate;" +
                "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;" +
                "void main()" +
                "{" +
                "gl_Position = position;" +
                "textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate;" +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;                            \n" +
                "uniform samplerExternalOES s_texture;               \n" +
                "void main(void) {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, textureCoordinate );\n" +
                //"  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n" +
                "}";

private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer, textureVerticesBuffer, vertexBuffer2;
private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer, buf2;
private int mProgram;
private int mPositionHandle, mPositionHandle2;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mTextureCoordHandle;


// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;
static float squareVertices[] = { // in counterclockwise order:
        -1.0f, -1.0f,   // 0.left - mid
        1.0f, -1.0f,   // 1. right - mid
        -1.0f, 1.0f,   // 2. left - top
        1.0f, 1.0f,   // 3. right - top

};


private short drawOrder[] = {0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3}; // order to draw vertices
private short drawOrder2[] = {2, 0, 3, 3, 0, 1}; // order to draw vertices

static float textureVertices[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f,  // A. left-bottom
        1.0f, 1.0f,  // B. right-bottom
        0.0f, 0.0f,  // C. left-top
        1.0f, 0.0f   // D. right-top
};

private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

private ByteBuffer indexBuffer;    // Buffer for index-array

private int texture;
private CardboardOverlayView mOverlayView;
private CardboardView cardboardView;
private SurfaceTexture surface;
private float[] mView;
private float[] mCamera;

public void startCamera(int texture) {
    surface = new SurfaceTexture(texture);
    surface.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

    camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);

  // Check what resolutions are supported by your camera
    /*List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();

    // Iterate through all available resolutions and choose one.
    // The chosen resolution will be stored in mSize.
    Camera.Size mSize = null;
    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Available resolution: " + size.width + "x" + size.height);
        mSize = size;
    }
    params.setPictureSize(5312,2988);*/

    camera.setParameters(params);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "CAM LAUNCH FAILED");
    }

}

static private int createTexture() {
    int[] texture = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texture, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture[0]);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    return texture[0];
}


private int loadGLShader(int type, String code) {
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, code);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    // Get the compilation status.
    final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

    // If the compilation failed, delete the shader.
    if (compileStatus[0] == 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error compiling shader: " + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
        shader = 0;
    }

    if (shader == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating shader.");
    }

    return shader;
}

/**
 * Checks if we've had an error inside of OpenGL ES, and if so what that error is.
 *
 * @param func
 */
private static void checkGLError(String func) {
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.e(TAG, func + ": glError " + error);
        throw new RuntimeException(func + ": glError " + error);
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the view to our CardboardView and initializes the transformation matrices we will use
 * to render our scene.
 *
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cardboardView = (CardboardView) findViewById(R.id.cardboard_view);
    cardboardView.setRenderer(this);
    setCardboardView(cardboardView);

    mCamera = new float[16];
    mView = new float[16];
    mOverlayView = (CardboardOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.overlay);
    //mOverlayView.show3DToast("Pull the magnet when you find an object.");
}

@Override
public void onRendererShutdown() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onRendererShutdown");
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(int width, int height) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceChanged");
}

/**
 * Creates the buffers we use to store information about the 3D world. OpenGL doesn't use Java
 * arrays, but rather needs data in a format it can understand. Hence we use ByteBuffers.
 *
 * @param config The EGL configuration used when creating the surface.
 */
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(EGLConfig config) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceCreated");
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.5f); // Dark background so text shows up well

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareVertices.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(squareVertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureVertices.length * 4);
    bb2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureVerticesBuffer = bb2.asFloatBuffer();
    textureVerticesBuffer.put(textureVertices);
    textureVerticesBuffer.position(0);

    int vertexShader = loadGLShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = loadGLShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

    texture = createTexture();
    startCamera(texture);
}

/**
 * Prepares OpenGL ES before we draw a frame.
 *
 * @param headTransform The head transformation in the new frame.
 */
@Override
public void onNewFrame(HeadTransform headTransform) {
    float[] mtx = new float[16];
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    surface.updateTexImage();
    surface.getTransformMatrix(mtx);
}

@Override
public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture arg0) {
    this.cardboardView.requestRender();
}

/**
 * Draws a frame for an eye. The transformation for that eye (from the camera) is passed in as
 * a parameter.
 *
 * @param transform The transformations to apply to render this eye.
 */
@Override
public void onDrawEye(EyeTransform transform) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture);


    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "position");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);


    mTextureCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "inputTextureCoordinate");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false, vertexStride, textureVerticesBuffer);

    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "s_texture");


    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);


    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordHandle);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mView, 0, transform.getEyeView(), 0, mCamera, 0);

}

@Override
public void onFinishFrame(Viewport viewport) {
}

@Override
public void onCardboardTrigger() {

}


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ui_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView
    android:id="@+id/cardboard_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<com.oculab.mehmettaha.vrcamera.CardboardOverlayView
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Don' t forget the importing libraries such as cardboard.jar and libprotobuf-java-...jar

Finally, you should get the result like this:

[image: Camera on Google Cardboard]

Cheers!

Comment: I have tried following your code example. I am unable to get it to work correctly. The only problems I have faced is in the `onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture arg0) {
        this.cardboardView.requestRender();}` and `onDrawEye(EyeTransform transform)` I'm sure these are simple fixes, but I am stuck.