# Android: render textureview of 2D video in side-by-side

Tags: android, google-cardboard, textureview, android-textureview

I am trying to create an video player app which is capable of displaying a 2D video in a side-by-side projection for cardboard. The input is a 2D video, so no need for head tracking. I checked the Google Cardboard SDKs but they don't provide an implementation for simple side-by-side projections with Non-3D or 360° contents.

My current implementation of the video player already uses a `TextureView` to render the video.

I found a sample code for side-by-side-camera preview: [[android Side By Side Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881389/android-side-by-side-camera)

How do I get the output from the `TextureView` of my video player into a `GvrView`?

Comment: Did you find any solution to your question?

Comment: Yes, and it was surprisingly easy. All you have to do is to get the surface of the textureview and bind it to the GvrView. The GvrView does all the rest.

Comment: Can you share some sample code on how you did it? Currently, I have an Activity where I am playing 2D video using texture view. But, how do I use a GrrView now?